# htaccess do not redirect if url is wrong

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

http://www.test.com/test/test2/dresses.html

When I call this URL, I want to redirect as below:

```
RewriteRule ^test/test2/(.*).html /index.php?dir=category&action=$1 [QSA]
```

but some of the URL like `http://www.test.com/test/test2/bad.html` does not exist and it displays a 404 page so I don't want to redirect bad URL and is that possible?

Comment: .htaccess rules don't know the difference between `bad.html` and `dresses.html` so you will have to handle this in php code only.

Comment: @anubhava thank you for yours suggestion and I will do in php code instead then